# Exponential number with negative base?

Tags: output-formatting

Consider the following number:

```
(-1)^(2/3)
```

I want to get output in real field, equal with:

```
(-1)^2 = 1, 1^(1/3) = 1
```

Thus

```
(-1)^(2/3) =1
```

Comment: But .... `(-1)^(2/3) // ComplexExpand`

Comment: Consider `Solve[a^3 == 1, a]`

Comment: Dear DR. belisarius, I want to obtain this output: (-1)^(2/3) =((-1)^2)^(1/3)=1^(1/3)=1

Comment: There was a book, **NKM** I think. Let me see if I find the reference

Comment: The point is that the number `(-1)^(2/3)`, which equals `-(1 + I Sqrt[3])/2`, is not the same number as `1`. It's not generally safe to treat it as equivalent to `1`. There are several possibilities that occur to me. (1) You want the number `1`; well, type `1` then and just avoid the powers. (2) If you wish to enter a strange form of `1`, then the standard, real, principal root is expressed with `Surd`: `Surd[-1, 3]^2` is what you're after. (3) Assuming it's not about input, and (1) & (2) are irrelevant, but it comes from a calculation, then my first remark applies. You shouldn't change it.

Comment: Use `Surd`. As in `In[4]:= Surd[-1,3]^2                                                            

Out[4]= 1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(-1)^(2/3) /. Power[x_, y_] :> (x^Numerator[y])^(1/Denominator[y])

(*1*)
```

Comment: Might want to try it on `(-2)^(2/3)`...

Comment: @MichaelE2, sorry for silly mistake and thanks for notifying (answer updated) :)

Comment: Ah, that's better! :)  [Forgive me for not upvoting. While it does what the OP requests, and rather well, too, I don't think it's an algebraically sound thing to do and should not generally be encouraged. See my comment to the question. There is probably a better way to deal with the problem, esp. if *Mathematica* is producing an answer containing `(-1)^(2/3)`. At present the question is stated too generally to answer in such a way.]